# Switch with 2 terminals and 3 wires

Tags: wiring, switch, light

I am Trying to replace a switch, and I noticed the old switch has 3 wires between 2 terminals. All the wires are black and there’s no ground. How would I go about wiring this to a new switch?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The backstab connections are each connected to the matching screw on the side. So you have:

- Power from panel and power to next unswitched device (receptacle, another switch, etc.) in the screw and the backstab above it.
- Switched power in the other backstab.

Get a new switch. Make sure it has "screw to clamp". That allows you to use straight-in wiring (like a backstab) but reliable (unlike a backstab) and two on each screw (unlike a backstab or a regular screw terminal). Spend $2 or $3 (look for "commercial grade" or "clamp" in the specifications) instead of 85 cents - it is money well spent to make the wiring simpler.

The alternative is to use ordinary screw terminals and make a pigtail. That's a short piece of (in this case black) wire that you attach to the original wires with a wire nut and attach the other end to the screw with the usual "hook". But simpler and easier to use screw-to-clamp.